# Calculate limit involving the antiderivative of a function

Tags: integration, limits

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) = e^{x^2}$. Now, consider $F$ an antiderivative of $f$.

Calculate: $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{xF(x)}{f(x)}$.

I couldn't find the antiderivative of $f$, and besides finding $F$, I have no other ideas.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: try L'Hôpital's rule

Comment: I don't think I can use it because I don't know the limit of $F$.

Comment: it dosent matter, as $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x) $is $\infty $

Answer (score 1):

Hint: By the fundamental theorem of calculus we have
\begin{align}
F(x) = \int^x_0 e^{t^2}\ dt + C
\end{align}
is an anti-derivative of $f(x)$. Observe $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} F(x) = \infty$.

Comment: why do you need both denominator and numerator to tend to $\infty$? In Baby rudin, it is proved if only denominator is divergent, we can still apply L'Hôpital rule

Comment: True. I'm only assuming the OP is only taking calculus.

Answer (score 1):

You actually need to find $F.$  And $f$ cannot be integrated into elementary functions anyway.

Can we agree that the limit seems to be going to $\frac {\infty}{\infty}$?

Use L'Hopitals rule.

$\frac {d}{dx} x F(x) = F(x) + xF'(x) = F(x) + xf(x)\\
\frac {d}{dx} f(x) = 2x f(x)$

After differentiating top and bottom, we have $\frac {F(x) + xf(x)}{2xf(x)}$

Still indeterminate.

When we apply L'Hopital's one more time, every term will have an $f(x)$ in it, and we can cancel top and bottom.